# Error upgrading Rollup build to latest @angular/2.4.8

Tags: angular, rollup, angular-compiler-cli

I'm running into an error with Rollup after compiling my Angular 2 app with ngc. Has anyone else overcome this issue?

```
Error: '$$observable' is not exported by  node_modules/rxjs/symbol/observable.js
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
```

Here is my package.json:

`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.16",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "https": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/karma": "^0.13.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "chokidar": "^1.6.0",
    "clim": "^1.1.1",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.3",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "cssnano": "^3.8.0",
    "google-closure-compiler": "^20160911.0.0",
    "google-closure-compiler-js": "^20160916.0.0",
    "htmlprocessor": "^0.2.4",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
    "karma": "1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
    "karma-verbose-reporter": "0.0.3",
    "live-server": "^1.1.0",
    "livereload": "^0.6.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
    "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^3.0.0",
    "onchange": "^3.0.2",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "postcss": "^5.2.5",
    "postcss-cli": "^2.6.0",
    "protractor": "^4.0.10",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.7.0",
    "replace-in-file": "^2.0.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-alias": "^1.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-angular": "=0.4.2",
    "rollup-plugin-cleanup": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-includepaths": "^0.2.1",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^1.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^0.8.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.5",
    "traceur": "0.0.111",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslint": "^3.15.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "watchify": "^3.7.0"
  }`

Comment: OK I see whats happening. After I had to deprecate rxjs-es I need to now figure out what is trying to import Observable and probably use `rollup-plugin-commonjs` to resolve this issue. Anyone have a sample `rollup.config.js` that works with ngc and the latest Angular?

Answer (score 1):

OK it works with these dependencies:

`"dependencies": {
      "@angular/common": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/compiler": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/core": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/forms": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/http": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.7",
      "@angular/router": "3.4.7",
      "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.8",
      "rxjs": "5.1.0",
      "systemjs": "0.20.7",
      "zone.js": "^0.7.6",
      "express": "^4.14.0",
      "http": "0.0.0",
      "https": "^1.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "@types/core-js": "^0.9.35",
      "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
      "@types/karma": "^0.13.33",
      "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
      "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
      "babel-cli": "^6.14.0",
      "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.14.0",
      "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
      "chalk": "^1.1.3",
      "chokidar": "^1.6.0",
      "clim": "^1.1.1",
      "codelyzer": "^2.0.1",
      "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
      "core-js": "^2.4.1",
      "cssnano": "^3.8.0",
      "google-closure-compiler": "^20160911.0.0",
      "google-closure-compiler-js": "^20160916.0.0",
      "htmlprocessor": "^0.2.4",
      "http-server": "^0.9.0",
      "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
      "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^2.4.0",
      "karma": "1.3.0",
      "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
      "karma-coverage": "^1.0.0",
      "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.3.4",
      "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
      "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
      "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.0.3",
      "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.0",
      "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.2.1",
      "karma-verbose-reporter": "0.0.3",
      "live-server": "^1.1.0",
      "livereload": "^0.6.0",
      "node-sass": "^3.10.1",
      "nodemon": "^1.10.2",
      "npm-run-all": "^3.0.0",
      "onchange": "^3.0.2",
      "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
      "postcss": "^5.2.5",
      "postcss-cli": "^2.6.0",
      "protractor": "^4.0.10",
      "remap-istanbul": "^0.7.0",
      "replace-in-file": "^2.0.1",
      "rimraf": "^2.5.1",
      "rollup": "^0.41.4",
      "rollup-plugin-alias": "^1.2.0",
      "rollup-plugin-angular": "=0.4.2",
      "rollup-plugin-cleanup": "^1.0.0",
      "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
      "rollup-plugin-includepaths": "^0.2.1",
      "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
      "rollup-plugin-replace": "^1.1.1",
      "rollup-plugin-typescript": "^0.8.1",
      "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
      "shelljs": "^0.7.5",
      "traceur": "0.0.111",
      "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
      "tslint": "^4.3.0",
      "typescript": "~2.1.6",
      "watchify": "^3.7.0"
    }`

and this rollup.config.js

```js
import replace from 'rollup-plugin-replace';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import cleanup from 'rollup-plugin-cleanup';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';

export default {
  entry: 'main.prod.js',
  format: 'iife',
  dest: 'dist/bundle.es2015.js',
  sourceMap: false,
  treeshake: true,
  plugins: [
    replace({ 'ENVIRONMENT': JSON.stringify( 'production' ) }),
    commonjs({
     include: 'node_modules/rxjs/**'
    }),
    resolve({ jsnext: true, module: true }),
    cleanup()
  ],
  onwarn: function ( message ) {
    if ( /at the top level of an ES module, and has been rewritten/.test( message ) ) {
      return;
    }
    console.error( message );
  }
}
```